# Command Line to open ReadMe file when opening project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to open a ReadMe.html file located in my project/solution as soon as Visual Studio is opened. Is there any command line switch to open ReadMe.html file of my project?

For Example,
Devenv myproj.csproj **/F:ReadMe.html**

Note: I want to automate this through a program, so not looking for manual solution to open Visual Studio and click on ReadMe file :)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!!!

I was able to open ReadMe html file in browser window inside VS as soon as the solution/project is opened. Below is the command:

devenv.exe WebApplication1.sln **/Command "Navigate [FilePath]\Project_Readme.html"**

FYI, Visual Studio has number of command line switches, the one useful here was "**/Command**" switch. It Starts the VS IDE and executes the command specified after the /Command switch.

The commands in question are not DOS commands, they are visual studio commands you can execute inside VS. Here is the reference for [Visual Studio Commands with Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c338aexd(v=vs.80).aspx).

Hope that helps someone else too!

Comment: Btw, If you want to open it in Edit mode, you can use below command:
devenv.exe WebApplication1.sln /Command "File.OpenFile [FilePath]\Project_Readme.html"